WP Rocket plugin causing issues while duplicating/publishing content
I've wordpress and receive technical issue email that states "WordPress caught an error with one of your plugins, WP Rocket." website is https://northbaysolutions.com/
The Issue occures when duplicate/publish the post and pages.
I tried to deactivate and reinstall the plugin but issue is still there, looks like the issue came after the recent updates of the plugin. I'm not the programmer so need expert guidance.
This is not about only debuggin the plugin but has issues after the update of specific plugin.
Thanks in advance.

You can enable debugging in WordPress to see more detailed error messages.
Add the following lines to your wp-config.php
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);

Clear Cache And see what's going on.
